# Prince "FAMD object has no attribute 'plot_row_coordinates'"

Tags: python, data-science, pca

As far as I can tell, this is the same implementation as every example of this function that I could find.
Calling famd.plot_row_coordinates() produces: 'FAMD' object has no attribute 'plot_row_coordinates'.
The prior lines run fine.

```
#FAMD
famd = FAMD(n_components = 10, n_iter = 3, random_state = 101)
famd.fit(df.drop('Target', axis=1)) #leave out response variable 'Target'
famd.eigenvalues_summary

#plot components
famd.transform(df)
famd.plot_row_coordinates(
    df.head(200),
    figsize = (15,10),
    color_labels=['Completion status: {}'.format(t) for t in df['Target']]
)
```

Comment: From which module are you importing `FAMD`?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'plot_row_coordinates' function got removed from the package on 22nd of February. You should now either use 'famd.plot' function or plot coordinates yourself, with code looking something like this:

```
coordinates = famd.row_coordinates(X)
x = coordinates[0].astype(np.float)
y = coordinates[1].astype(np.float)
plt.plot(x,y)
```